# color on each iteration of loop using a div

Tags: php

I am wondering how to change this :

This code is using a table and I instead trying to use a div, but I wanna define the div the same way it's done with `enter <td>. In <td class= '".$class." thum'> here`
Like `enter <div class='".$class." thumb'> here`

```
enter <td ' class='".$class." thumb'><div align='center'><a href='show-".$row['id'].".php'><img src='".$row['image']."' width='80' height='60' /></a></div></td> here
```

I am trying to change color on each iteration of loop. That's what $class is there.

I don't think this is clear at all. It's hard to explain it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a new value within each loop prior to echoing the output. For instance, if you wanted "zebra stripes," you could check if the current iteration is even or odd:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $items ); $i++ ) {
  $style = ( $i % 2 == 0 ) ? $styleA : $styleB ;
  echo "<td class='{$style} thumb'>...</td>";
}
```

Sample Output: http://codepad.org/8cYyiBBH

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work when I use a div. echo "<div class='{$style} thumb'>...</div>"; It works for TD though

Comment: @Rocks It will work for any element. It will work for `div` as well, unless your class is defined with the expectation that it will be used with a `td`, like `td.foo { color: red }`. That, for obvious reasons, wouldn't work when the class is added to a `div`.